# azure-functions-core-tools : while running "func init" command fails

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions-core-tools

On executing 'func init' command from an empty directory to create a azure function fails with following error:

```
events.js:298
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Users\<XYZ>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin/func ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:\\Users\\<XYZ>\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin/func',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\<XYZ>\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\azure-functions-core-tools\\bin/func',
  spawnargs: [ 'init' ]
}
```

Anyone any suggestions on the same?

Comment: sounds like something you should create an issue for in their github repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues

Comment: Seems like this one: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1804

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the update @silent .
Googling the same, I also did land into the same link.

To followup on the suggestions at the Github, I had to perform following steps:

1. Go to the folder:

```
C:\Users\< XYZ >\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools
```

2. Open the package.json file in an editor
3. Modify the version for "unzipper" module under dependencies from '0.10.5' to '0.10.8'.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "chalk": "3.0.0",
    "command-exists": "1.2.8",
    "glob": "7.1.6",
    "https-proxy-agent": "3.0.1",
    "progress": "2.0.3",
    "rimraf": "3.0.0",
    "tmp": "0.1.0",
    "unzipper": "0.10.8"
  },
```

4. Delete "node_modules" folder under this directory.
5. Run "npm install" command from this directory on command-prompt.

Remember to replace "< XYZ >" with your own Username on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

For now, if this happens you can follow these steps to mitigate yourselves --

```
Go to the installed location.C:\<project>\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\ in the example above.
Run npm install unzipper@0.10.7
Run node .\lib\install.js from that directory
```

These steps should download and extract the core-tools to the bin location and have it setup for executions.
Please let us know if you continue to see issues.